# Four questions concerning dual graphs

Tags: graph-theory

What are the (combinatorial/algebraic) conditions that the [dual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph) - resp. the ([weak dual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph#Weak_dual)) - of a planar graph is

- unique (independent of its embedding),
- simple (and not a multi-graph)?

Are these four questions logically independent of each other?

Comment: Are you consider planar graphs?